# jQuery validate group validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validate plugin. I have 3 fields, and need to validate them only if one of 
them is not empty, otherwise do not validate at all.

```
<input type="text" data-validate="{validate:{required:true, 
messages:{required:'Flickr set is required'}}}" id="flickr_set" name="flickr_set">


<input type="text" data-validate="{validate:{required:true, 
messages:{required:'Flickr ID is required'}}}" id="flickr_id" name="flickr_id">

<input type="text" data-validate="{validate:{required:true,
positiveNumber:true, messages:{required:'Photos count is required',
positiveNumber:'Positive number is required'}}}" id="flickr_photos-count" name="flickr_photos-count">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [dependency-callback](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback) method of the validation plugin.

What this will allow you to do is:

> Makes the element required, depending on the result of the given callback.

You can then place a `required` validation rule on the 3 fields that says this field will only be required based on the return from the function callback; you can then put a rule on the fields to say require this field if any of the fields are not blank `return true`, or don't require this field if all the fields are blank `return false`

Thus if any of the fields are filled in they all become required, if they're all left empty none of them are required.

```
rules: {
    flickr_set: {
        required: function(element) {
            return ($("#flickr_set").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_id").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_photos-count").is(':empty') ? false : true);
        }
    },
    flickr_id: {
        required: function(element) {
            return ($("#flickr_set").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_id").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_photos-count").is(':empty') ? false : true);
        }
    },
    flickr_photos-count: {
        required: function(element) {
            return ($("#flickr_set").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_id").is(':empty') && $("#flickr_photos-count").is(':empty') ? false : true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just da a

```
$("form").validate();
```

And give the input fields a class required.

If you want to have custom messages you can change above javascript to:

```
$("form").validate({
    messages : {
        flickr_set : "Flickr set is required",
        flickr_id : "Flickr ID",
        flickr_photos-count : "Photos count is required"
    }
});
```